# Understanding the one-writer, many-readers problem?

Tags: concurrency, synchronization

I need some help understanding the implementation of the one-writer many-readers problem shown below as I am new to this concept:

[image]

I have a rough idea that there will be starvation/deadlock among the readers as there is one writer that multiple readers are trying to access at once. Can anyone please provide some further insight regarding the problems with the implementation of this situation?

I am not looking for any coding, that was just the sample code (pseudocode) I am working with. I am looking for the problem of the implementation. Upon further research I have assumed the following (based on the line: `if readcount == 1 then semWait(wrt);` :

- There is one writer and many readers
- The readers have priority over the writers
- The possible problem: The writers cannot write until the reader has finished reading therefore starvation occurs

However upon re-evaluation of the code I have also assumed the following based on the lines:

```
semWait(mutex);
readcount := readcount - 1;
if readcount == 0 then up
semSignal(mutex);
```

Could I not also say that only one reader may read at a time therefore the other readers will be starved?

Therefore would either of these be the correct way of interpreting the coding to the problem is of the implementation or would I be wrong?

Comment: Please don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics (note that you can [use LaTeX](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands)) and don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources!

Comment: As far as the question: What are your thoughts?  What possible problems have you considered, and what are your thoughts on whether they are or aren't present in this code?  "provide further insight regarding the problems with this code" is a bit open-ended/vague.  The more specific you can make your question, and the more you show us about what work you've done so far, the more likely that you will get helpful answers.

Comment: @D.W. I have edited the details in my question to meet some of the points you brought up in your first comment. I do apologise for using an image but I could not copy and paste the code as it was presented to me as an image already.

Comment: Be specific about what you are asking. Do you want to know if the protocol you have described is correct? (i.e. satisfies the requirements of priority and not allowing simultaneous read/write). If so, note that even the simplest protocol where no one gets to read/write is correct. Are you asking whether your protocol is correct and is deadlock,starvation free? Note that formal proofs might be trickier than you expect.

Comment: @Ariel The only information I was given about this coding sample was: "Explain the problem with implementation of the one-writer many-readers
problem". That's all, the rest is a bit of a mystery to me, but based on the information it implies there is definitely a problem. Based on what I understand by the coding, I see it as many readers have priority over one writer and I am assuming that the writer may be starved. But I am not sure, it is all a guess based on what I know and the research I have found. What I'm looking for here is validation or correction on my assumption

Comment: If you're not sure what the problem statement means, I suggest you ask whoever gave you that problem statement for clarification -- we can't read minds.  If you can't tell exactly what the problem is asking, then we probably won't, either.  Note that simply copy-pasting a problem statement and expecting us to solve it for you isn't really what this site is for.  We want to help you understand the concepts, but solving your exercise for you probably won't help you or anyone else.  (You might also want to edit the question to provide the context and where you ran across this problem statement.)

Comment: As far as the image: I recommend that you type in the code from the image directly into a code block.  I do realize that it's not possible to copy-paste text from an image; that's why I suggested in my earlier comment that you transcribe the text.  And don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources.  Copying others material without attribution could potentially be viewed as plagiarism, which isn't welcome here.

Comment: @D.W. I am not trying to ask anyone to solve anything. I am just seeking validation (is what I have deduced correct or not). The person who gave me the problem refuses to give further clarification. It appears that the coding is pseudocode (based on what my peers have determined). The assumptions I have mentioned in my question is the style of answering that is required and the information I was able to get from further research but I am a bit inexperienced with this topic therefore I am just seeking validation on what I have found so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First,I would suggest (in the future as well) to write the pseudocode yourself (the commands for the readers/writers), It will be cleaner and easier to read than the image. Also, i would suggest briefly explaining the semantics of your operations (wait/signal/up, since you used all three in the code).

To your answer, readers not being able to read simultaneously does not mean starvation, although simultaneous reading ability is an additional requirement, at least in the classical formulation of the problem (moreover, readers can read simultaneously in this protocol). Starvation means that there exists a process stuck waiting while other processes share the resource (if one reader $r_1$ has to wait until $r_2$ is done, then he might read after $r_2$, who eventually will be done reading, so $r_1$ is not stuck).

This protocol (as  it seems to me) is the same as the one described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writers_problem) (under First readers-writers problem). It is easy to see (as mentioned in the link) that writers can be starved here. Suppose $r_1,r_2$ are reading at the same time, so the count is $2$. Imagine a scenario where whenever $r_1,r_2$ read together, the first to finish (and decrements the counter to $1$) immediately requests reading again (so the counter is back to $2$). This way the counter will never reach $0$ and the writer will be starved (stuck waiting).